# ¿Cómo modificar variable de ambiente en .Net Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Mi idea es guardar en una variable de ambiente la cadena de conexión y luego utilizarla en la clase StartUp, logro obtenerla de la siguiente forma:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["CadenaConexion"]));  
    }
```

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
    public IActionResult PostCadenaConexion([FromBody] Configuracion configuracion)
    {
        EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider configurationProvider = new EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider();

        configurationProvider.Set("CadenaConexion",configuracion.CadenaConexion);
    }
```

Mi idea es crear una interfaz donde un usuario pueda configurar la conexión a la db.

Comment: Esto es raro. Si estas en un entorno cliente servidor, para que querrias que se conecte a otra DB?

Comment: La aplicacion esta dividida en dos partes, el cliente (usuario final) y la otra parte el super administrador (este tiene que poder configurar por ejemplo la cadena de conexion, tambien el servidor y puerto para smpt (envio de email)

Comment: Ah perfecto ya entendi tu escenario.. En gral se modifican a mano.. pero es interesante saber si se puede hacer por sistema...

Comment: Si, eso tambien me gustaria jeje, pero me arte de buscar info, te recomiendan usar secretos de usuario, pero eso sirve en desarrollo, tambien variables de ambientes, pero es lo mismo que el app settings, podes leer la key o variable pero no modificarla, asi que ni idea de como hacerlo :(

Comment: En ese caso es mas recomendable que tengas una base de datos con tablas para tus usuarios y conexiones, de tal manera que si tiene una o mas opciones el usuario pueda seleccionar su conexion, o crear una nueva.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es no modificar variables de entorno, es algo bastante inseguro porque como bien indica el nombre, son de entorno y se ubican en la infraestructura(server). Ademas si las modificas dinamicamente, colicionarian ambos sistemas.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo.

1) En la tabla del usuario administrador, pones un campo para cada valor que se deba configurar dinámicamente. De esta forma en cualquier lado donde tengas referencia la usuario tendrás esa información y ademas quedaran guardados para la próxima vez que el admin inicie sesión (sumale que si tenes N cantidad de admin, cada uno tendrá su propia configuracion)

2) En variables de sesión. Esta es mas fácil pero deberías manejar la concurrencia ya que varios admins pueden estar trabajando y cada uno pondrá su propia configuración por lo que comienza a complicarse

3) Dejaría la variable de sesión (que configuras en el archivo de configuración o bien desde azure o docker o donde sea que estés deployando) para el connectionString de la base de datos principal donde esta toda la configuración y datos de la aplicación.